# Converting BLOB's to UTF-8 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I am unable to add UTF-8 collation to one of my columns in my database.
The column is a BLOB, it's currently got BINARY attr.

Every time I change it in phpmyadmin, no changes take effect even though phpmyadmin returns no errors.

Is BLOB not capable of settings the UTF-8 collation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Blobs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) have no character set nor collation (the manual page points to [varbinary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html) where this is explained). The equivalent of a blob, but with character set and collation is a TEXT column (same manual page as the blob).

phpMyAdmin seems to be, to say the least, unclear in its operation. I have not been able to find a [related bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/search/?q=blob).

Comment: My phpmyadmin (3.3.10) doesn't dispatch any error or alert message when I try to change BLOB encoding ether. This option shouldn't be available for BLOB IMO.